# Issues with async retrieved data in component logic

Tags: angular, typescript, angular9

I've got a call to a service that retrieves data from the server (strings, used in the UI) which is performed before any component is initiated and the problem is that the data is available in the component's template, but not in the code though, which is weird.

I put it in `ngOnInit` of my main `AppComponent`

```
ngOnInit() { 
    this.dataContractService.getUIStrings();
}
```

This is indeed invoked before any other component's `ngOnInit` so the strings will (should) be available to them.

Here `getUIStrings` code:

```
async getUIStrings() {
    let url = "/datacontract/getuistrings";
    let promise = await this.http.get<APIResponse>(url).pipe(map(x => { return x.responsePayload })).toPromise<any>();
    this.globals.UIStrings = promise.strings; //
}
```

I put the results in `globals` which is an injectable service, injected in components that need access to `UIStrings`.

Here's an example of how I use it

```
export class DashboardComponent {

    constructor(
        public globals: Globals,
    ) { }

    dashboardMessage: string;

    ngOnInit() {
        if (condition) {
            this.dashboardMessage = this.globals.UIStrings["DashboardAdminDesc"];
        }
        else {
            this.dashboardMessage = this.globals.UIStrings["DashboardDesc"];
        }

    }

}
```

In the code, `UIStrings` is an empty array, but in the above component's template, it's available an populated.

```
{{globals.UIStrings["DashboardAdminDesc"]}}
```

This works. What am I doing wrong here ?

Comment: `let promise = await this.http...` just a note that since you are `await`ing, that variable isn't going to be a promise so the name is misleading.

Comment: httpClient itself returns observable and you just need to subscribe it. Rather than using promise, use Observable keeping the code clean and following best practices.

Comment: @DurgeshPal how do I load data before any other component tries to access it then ?

Answer (score 0):

The problems are,

1. `appcomponent's` `ngOnInit` will be called first and so `getUIStrings` function will be called. it's `promise` will eventually be resolved and assigned result to `this.globals.UIStrings`. (Assume promise takes 5 mins to resolve)
2. When promise is still in process, `DashboardComponent` is loaded and `this.dashboardMessage` will be `undefined` as `this.globals.UIStrings` **doesn't have any data yet**.
3. in html, if you use `{{globals.UIStrings["DashboardAdminDesc"]}}`, it will work because at some point of time `this.globals.UIStrings` is going to have data when promise is resolved. in HTML, `this.globals` is referenced type. so If you change it from service, it will directly be available in any HTML where it is being used (not in `.ts` file)

   **But** if you use `{{this.dashboardMessege}}` , it will always remain `undefined` because `dashboard's` `ngOnInit` is executing before the promise is resolved.

---

### Solution

I'm giving you some idea. Since code is not tested, don't expect it to work properly. I don't touch `this.globals.UIStrings` in below code snippet. You can refactor below code as per your need.

**NOTE:** This type of solution is required since your `dashboard component` is executing before promise is resolved. So there is no sync between app & dashboard components.

**global.service**

```
  response = new Subject<any>();  // consider response is your globals.UIStrings


async getUIStrings() {
    let url = "/datacontract/getuistrings";
    let promise = await this.http.get<APIResponse>(url).pipe(map(x => { return x.responsePayload })).toPromise<any>();
            
    this.response.next(promise.strings);                      // data will be emitted for here
}
```

**Dashboard.component.ts**

```
export class DashboardComponent {
    dashboardMessage: string;

    constructor(
        public globals: Globals,
    ) { 
              
               this.globals.response.subscribe(data=>{     // data will be received here

                  if (condition) {
                     this.dashboardMessage = data["DashboardAdminDesc"];
                  }
                  else {
                     this.dashboardMessage = data["DashboardDesc"];
                  }
                  
               })
     }
}
```

**.html**

```
  {{dashboardMessge}} will always output desire result
```